# Inference of Gradient Boosting on test istance

Tags: predictive-models, boosting, gradient

According to my professor, Gradient Boosting can be done using the following algorithm:

[image]

Now, I do not really understand the inference part of that algorithm.
Why cannot we not simply return $F^{(K)}(x)$, which was returned in step $6$ of the algorithm? Moreover, does this method not imply that we have to keep track of each ensemble $f^{k}$ and the respective paramter $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In gradient boosting we return the sequence of functions $F^{(k)}(x)$, $k=1, \dots, K$, $K$ being the number of trees/base learners used. $F^{(K)}(x)$ on it's own is has only learned to "correct" against the residuals done by the ensemble of the prior $K-1$ base learners. So if we returned just $F^{(K)}(x)$ *only* we would only do a minor addition against $F^{(0)}(x) =0$.
2. In the "classic" gradient boosting paper by [Friedman (2001)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-29/issue-5/Greedy-function-approximation-A-gradient-boostingmachine/10.1214/aos/1013203451.full) $\alpha$ which the  "step-length" in the the function space is indeed variable and found by line-search (the paper denotes is by $\rho$, see Eq. 8). This is indeed means that we need to keep track of it. Future implementations realised that a small but stable $\rho$ is good enough for practical purposes and making the direction of that step more relevant is how we get  a better bang of our (Stats) buck. (e.g. that's why [XGBoost](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754) uses [Newton's steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization)/second-order approximations via the Hessian instead of just the gradient.)

Comment: Can this 'inference formula' change, if for example we have a different loss function? Or is it always computed like that?

Comment: It won't really change as what using a different loss function would entail are changes at steps 3 & 4 (i.e. the concept of residuals and $k$-th base learner respectively) rather than the fact we are have an ensemble algorithm of weak learners.